# Проблемы с Авторизацией на сайте Python requests

Tags: javascript, python, requests

Я столкнулся с проблемой при попытке авторизоваться через библиотеку requests в Python. Проблема заключается в _abck кукках у сайта, генерация коих происходит на стороне сайта.
Почитав сеть при открытии главной страницы сайта, я увидел POST запрос вида sensor_data: {и далее большее кол-во данных}. Я пробовал копировать кукки через селениум вебдрайвер но это не практично и я бы хотел найти более удобного для себя решения. Меня интересуют два вопроса. Как можно обойти подобного рода защиту, или же как можно генерировать этот post запрос на своей стороне отсылая его браузеру. Буду благодарен любому ответу. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: вот [тут что-то рассматривали](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/182895/anti-bot-javascript-library-identification)

Comment: Копирование куков в selenium помогло? Почему не практично? Что мешает использовать куки в requests?

Comment: Можете представить свой вариант кода?